# How to generate a presentable table in R that counts/sums matches between string and numeric in different columns

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this:

Year  Type   Country    Size

1900   1        A    300
1901   1        A   359
1902   1        A   839
1903   1        A   35
1900   2        B   1235
1904   3        C   75
1901   4        B   100
1902   4        B  467
1903   4        B   2356
1904   4        B 6940
1905   4        B   34
1910   5        A   3424

1-5 are different types 
A-D are different countries

For some types (such as type 1) I have 4 years of consecutive data. For other (such as type 3) I only have 1 year of info. In the real data frame, for some types, I have 40 years of data.

Each type has a correspondent country, and I have a total of 5 different countries.

(In reality, this database is >10k lines and >15 countries.)

I would like to print a table that is presentable, with a formal layout which would tell me:

- How many unique types exist per country (Eg. country C=1, Country A=5 )
- Total Size per country, which sums all sizes per country (eg. country C = 175)

Thanks

Comment: Table Example:
Country Name: A   ;  Number of Types: 5    ;  Size of Types: 4957  (which is the sum of 300+359+839+35+3424)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

- Code

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, .(N = .N, Size = sum(Size)), by = .(Country)]
```

- Output

```r
#>    Country N  Size
#> 1:       A 5  4957
#> 2:       B 6 11132
#> 3:       C 1    75
```

- Your data

```r
df <- data.frame(Year = c(1900,1901,1902,1903,1900,1904,1901,1902,1903,1904,1905,1910),
                 Type = c(1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,5),
                 Country = c("A","A","A","A","B","C","B","B","B","B","B","A"),
                 Size = c(300,359,839,35,1235,75,100,467,2356,6940,34,3424))
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

We could use `gt` package.

```
library(dplyr)
library(gt)
df %>%
  group_by(Country) %>% 
  summarize(N = n(), Size=sum(Size)) %>% 
  gt()
```

[image]